# how to get filtered collection backpack laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a button that needs to pass a filtered collection from a table. Now when I click on the button, I get the entire collection
my button

```
$this->crud->addButtonFromView('top', 'withdrawDebtCompany', 'withdraw_debt', 'end');
```

button view

```
<form action="{{ url($crud->route.'/withdrawAllCompanyDebt') }}" method="POST">
    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-style="zoom-in">
        <span class="ladda-label">
             {{ trans('columns.debt.allwithdraw') }}
        </span>
    </button>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

method

```
public function withdrawDebtCompany()
    {
  
        $bills = $this->crud->query->get();
        Bill::tryWithdrawalsIncrement($bills);
        $res['success'] = 0;
        $res['err'] = 0;
        $bills->each(function($bill) use(&$res){
            $paym = new PaymentsController();
            $result = $paym->payDebt(new Request([
                'bill_id'=>$bill->id,
            ]));
            if($result['code'] == 0) {
                $res['success'] += 1;   
            } else {
                $res['err'] += 1;
           }
        });

        \Alert::add('warning', 'Успешно списано: '.$res['success'].' | Неуспешно списано: '. $res['err'])->flash();
        return redirect()->back();
        
    }
```

I tried tracking the filtered collection in the button method, but that doesn't work. This is where the whole collection comes in. Filtered collection only comes after page reload

Answer (score 0):

Hope to find you well.

In your `<form>` element you don't have any input to be POSTed, so I am wondering, why using a form there and not an `<a>` or similar.

I would advise you to have a look at the `ListOperation` https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/main/src/app/Http/Controllers/Operations/ListOperation.php

There you will find the `search` endpoint that is used by datatables to get it's data.

You can apply a similar solution in your button endpoint to get the filtered results like in table.

Cheers